# Pandas dropping columns and rows from a dataframe that came from Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop some useless columns in a dataframe but I am getting the error: "too many indices for array"

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
def answer_one():
    energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls")
    energy.drop(energy.index[0,1], axis = 1)
answer_one()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
Your syntax is wrong when slicing the index and it should be the columns

```
import pandas as pd

energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls")
energy.drop(energy.columns[[0,1]], axis=1)
```

---

**Option 2**
I'd do it like this

```
import pandas as pd

energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls")
energy.iloc[:, 2:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what about rows? What is the correct syntax for them because i cant seem to drop them either. @piRSquared

Comment: **Option 1**  `energy.drop(energy.index[[0,1]])`

Comment: **Option 2**  `energy.iloc[2:]`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to skip unneeded columns when parsing/reading Excel file:

```
energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls", usecols='C:ZZ')
```

Comment: OOM )-:  for like 4 hours!

Comment: @piRSquared, i know this feeling :-D

Comment: @Ali this is a very good answer and I'd up-vote it if I could.

Comment: If you are using Pandas >0.25 the keyword is called `usecols` instead of `parse_cols`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to drop the column need to change the syntax. You can refer to them by the header or the index. Here is how you would refer to them by name.

```
import pandas as pd

energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls")
energy.drop(['first_colum', 'second_column'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Another solution would be to exclude them in the first place:

```
energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls", usecols=[2:])
```

This will help speed up the import as well.

Comment: Second solution gives me error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Second solution is obviously wrong.